# Javascript eval ReferenceError is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was creating a dynamical variable off a string in my constructor. It was working fine but eventually, I got this error out of nowhere. I did not do anything that could break the system and the variable are defined as normal. For example, the lang will be `en` and the str will be `nep_tag` and I want to eval it to get `en.nep_tag` but I need it to be flexible so I can have another lang & str such as `fr` & `nep_tag2`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated ^^

ERROR:

> undefined 1:
>   en.nep_tag
>   ^
>   ReferenceError: en is not defined

Here is the code

```js
module.exports = Language;

function Language(lang) {
    this.get = function(str) {
        return eval(lang + '.' + str);
    }
}
```

I tried another method and it gives me the same error :

```js
let func = new Function(lang + '.' + str);
return func();
```

All of the str are stored in multiple files such as lang_EN etc like so :

```js
en = {
    nep_tag: "My message here",
    ...
}
```

It would be the same in the lang_FR one :

```js
fr = {
    nep_tag: "Mon message ici",
    ...
}
```

So anywhere in my code I can call the Language constructor to get the message in the desired language :

```
const Language = require("../../util/languages/language.js");
const lang = new Language(row.language); // en/fr/... are stored in a database and i made sure they were valid 
lang.get("nep_tag");
```

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, use an object or map.

Comment: Please don't use eval. eval is evil

Comment: remove eval (and parentheses) and keep lang + '.' + str and it should work

Comment: @ControlAltDel That won't work. The argument is a string, not an object.

Comment: `lang_map[lang][str]`

Comment: @Barmar Could you clarify ? How do I replace an eval with a map ?

Comment: `lang_map = {"en": { ... }, "fr": { ... }, "it": { ... } }`.

Comment: @Sawang_ can you log `row`?

Comment: @Ayush Gupta { Id: '421694325269856287',
  language: 'en'
}

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend getting rid of eval, using using objects.

For instance, you could have the following object:

```
const langMap = {
    en: {
        nep_tag: 'nep_tag'
    },
    fr: {
        nep_tag: 'nep_tag_fr'
    }
}
```

And extracting the value as

```
function GetLanguageString(lang, str) {
    return langMap[lang][str]
}
```

Working sample:

```js
const langMap = {
  en: {
    nep_tag: 'nep_tag'
  },
  fr: {
    nep_tag: 'nep_tag_fr'
  }
}

function GetLanguageString(lang, str) {
  return langMap[lang][str]
}


console.log(GetLanguageString('en', 'nep_tag'));
console.log(GetLanguageString('fr', 'nep_tag'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! The problem is that nep_tag is stored in a js file like so : en = { nep_tag: "My message here", ...} & the fr one is stored like that too in another js file. So that's why when I need it somewhere in my code I'm calling the constructor above with the eval and that would return me the message for the correct lang so I don't think i can store it in one single map :/

Comment: @Sawang_ How does your current eval get the `en` object right now? Please mention in the question